# Python fastapi post xml

Tags: python, xml, simplexml, fastapi, pydantic

Я хочу отправить запрос курлом с телом xml и получить этот же xml как ответ.
Мой запрос:

```
curl -X post http://host:port/api/v1/ -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Accept: application/xml" -d "<word>\"hi\"</word>"
```

Мой код:

```
from simplexml import dumps, loads
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Type, Any
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.responses import Response
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends

T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseModel)

class XmlData(BaseModel):
    word: str

class XmlBody(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, model_class: Type[T]):
        self.model_class = model_class

    async def __call__(self, request: Request) -> T:
        body = await request.body()
        dict_data = loads(body)
        return self.model_class.parse_obj(dict_data)

class XmlResponse(Response):
    media_type = "application/xml"

    def render(self, content: Any) -> bytes:
        return dumps({'response': content}).encode("utf-8")


app = FastAPI()

@app.post("api/v1/")
def post_data(data: XmlData = Depends(XmlBody(XmlData))):
    return XmlResponse(data)
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for XmlData
name
  str type expected (type=type_error.str)
```

Подскажите, где может быть ошибка и куда смотреть?

Comment: Вопрос будет закрыт, так как на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: @strawdog Спасибо, вопрос переведен.

Comment: @insolor готово

Comment: `simplexml.loads("<word>\"hi\"</word>")` возвращает `{'word': {'word': '"hi"'}}`. Я не работал с simplexml, не знаю почему так, но это точно не маппится на ваш класс XmlData (вложенный словарь не является строкой, поэтому и выдает ошибку валидации).

Comment: @insolor Да, Вы правы. при таком теле: "<Request><word>\"hi\"</word></Request>" получается другая ошибка. Буду смотреть дальше. Спасибо

Comment: @insolor покажете небольшие изменения?

Comment: Оформил полный ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ValidationError` возникает из-за того, что `simplexml.loads("<word>\"hi\"</word>")` возвращает `{'word': {'word': '"hi"'}}`, и это не соответствует модели `XmlData` (в словаре данные по ключу "word" - не строка, а вложенный словарь), поэтому и падает на вызове `self.model_class.parse_obj(dict_data)` с ошибкой валидации.

Корректным словарем для этой модели был бы словарь вида `{'word': '"hi"'}`.

Со входными данными `<Request><word>\"hi\"</word></Request>` (из комментариев к вопросу) получится словарь `{'Request': {'word': '"hi"'}}`. При попытке конвертировать в XmlData упадет с ошибкой валидации, на этот раз из-за того, что во внешнем словаре отсутствует ключ `"word"`:

```
>>> from pydantic import BaseModel                                              

>>> class XmlData(BaseModel): 
...     word: str                                                               

>>> XmlData.parse_obj({'Request': {'word': '"hi"'}})                            
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 578, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.parse_obj
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 406, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for XmlData
word
  field required (type=value_error.missing)

1 validation error for XmlData
word
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Тут по сути нужно сначала вытащить данные по ключу `'Request'`, и уже их конвертировать в XmlData:

```
>>> dict_data = {'Request': {'word': '"hi"'}}                                   

>>> XmlData.parse_obj(dict_data["Request"])                                     
XmlData(word='"hi"')
```

В вашем коде нужно изменить строку `return self.model_class.parse_obj(dict_data)` на `return self.model_class.parse_obj(dict_data["Request"])`.

Дальше уже будет падать при возврате результата с ошибкой `AttributeError: 'XmlData' object has no attribute 'items'`. Тут просто нужно данные перед передачей в `XmlResponse` преобразовать в словарь (`return XmlResponse(data.dict())`).

Ну и еще одна ошибка, путь в `@app.post()` нужно указывать с `/` в начале, иначе при запросе будет возвращаться ошибка `HTTP 404 Not found`.

Итого, получается такой код (измененные строки помечены комментарием `# <--`):

```py
from simplexml import dumps, loads
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Type, Any
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.responses import Response
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends

T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseModel)


class XmlData(BaseModel):
    word: str


class XmlBody(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, model_class: Type[T]):
        self.model_class = model_class

    async def __call__(self, request: Request) -> T:
        body = await request.body()
        dict_data = loads(body)
        return self.model_class.parse_obj(dict_data["Request"])  # <--


class XmlResponse(Response):
    media_type = "application/xml"

    def render(self, content: Any) -> bytes:
        return dumps({'response': content}).encode("utf-8")


app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/api/v1/")  # <--
def post_data(data: XmlData = Depends(XmlBody(XmlData))):
    return XmlResponse(data.dict())  # <--
```

Отправляем POST запрос, получаем ответ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<response>
    <word>\&quot;hi\&quot;</word>
</response>
```

[image: Скриншот]

Через curl (имя метода POST должно быть прописано капсом, иначе будет возвращать `HTTP 405` с телом `{"detail":"Method Not Allowed"}`):

```
❯ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/ -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Accept: application/xml" -d "<Request><word>\"hi\"</word></Request>"
<?xml version="1.0" ?><response><word>&quot;hi&quot;</word></response>%
```